# Of the two constructers one works and the other doesn't when the argument is correct

Tags: java

i'm new to programming. i don't understand why one of the constructers I'm using to check for the validity of the characters of a string argument in the constructer does not work. the constructer should check if the entered string contains only characters G,C,A,T, else it throws an `IllegalArgumentException`.

I tried using an array of characters to check for the validity of the string by using the `toCharArray()` method on the entered string. the constructer works for invalid strings, but not for valid strings. but another constructer i used works. please let me know why the first one doesn't.

//this is the first constructer that doesn't work for me

```
public class Fragment {
    private String nucleotideSequence;

    public Fragment(String nucleotides) throws IllegalArgumentException {

        char[] validityCheck = nucleotides.toCharArray();
        int validityCounter = 0;

        for (char c : validityCheck) {
            if(c != 'G' || c != 'C' || c != 'A' || c != 'T') {
                validityCounter++;
            }
        }

        if (validityCounter != 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid characters present");
        }

        nucleotideSequence = nucleotides;
    }
}
```

// this is the second constructer that works

```
public class Fragment {
    private String nucleotideSequence;

    public Fragment(String nucleotides) throws IllegalArgumentException {

        boolean k = false;

        for(int i = 0; i < nucleotides.length(); i++){

            char lol = nucleotides.charAt(i);
            if(lol=='A'||lol=='G'||lol=='C'||lol=='T'){
                k = true;
            }
            else{
                k = false;
            }

            if(k == false){
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Dosent work");
            }

            nucleotideSequence = nucleotides;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please review the correctness of the code formatting, there were closing curle braces '}' missing

Comment: you should consider renaming ```validityCounter``` so something that hints to counting errors (like ```errorCounter```).

Comment: Consider the following shorter code: `if (!nucleotideSequence.matches("[AGCT]+")) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid nucleotide sequence");`

Comment: validityCounter is actually counting 'invalidities' so it is named exactly backwards to its usage.  Names matter a lot to people trying to understand the code (maybe even to you, next week), so I'd advise fixing that nit.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem in the constructor that is not working is with the following 'if' statement:

```
if(c != 'G' || c != 'C' || c != 'A' || c != 'T')
```

This statement is always true. So the following:

```
    for (char c : validityCheck) {
        if(c != 'G' || c != 'C' || c != 'A' || c != 'T') {
            validityCounter++;
        }
    }
```

equals:

```
    for (char c : validityCheck) {
        validityCounter++;
    }
```

the correct statement would be

```
if(c != 'G' && c != 'C' && c != 'A' && c != 'T') {
```